# php PDO doesn't print out database values

Tags: php, html

I want to make a login page using html and php.
This is a method of inputting ID and password in html and passing the value to login.php in POST format.

here is my php code.

...

```
<body>
<?php
try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=user;host=localhost","root","");
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $id = $_POST[$id];
  $pw = $_POST[$password];
  $check = "SELECT password FROM user WHERE id = '$id'";
  $rows = $db->query($check);
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    print($row);
  }
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
?>
<p>Sorry, a database error occurred. Please try again later.</p>
<p>(Error details: <?= $ex->getMessage() ?>)</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

So I created a database for testing and
I wrote the above code to check if the values ​​are imported correctly in the php code
but no value is printed.
I checked there is a value in mysql's database.
How can I fix this?

Comment: `$pw = $_POST[$password];` what's the value of password?

Comment: It is the password received from html

Comment: it has to be like that `$_POST['password'];` I assume the field name is password

Comment: oh i see.. thank you very much!

Comment: working now? was that the issue?

Comment: but It just printed "Array". PDO->query returns array?

Comment: yes. it works now but It just print "Array" so I want know how I print real value in id and password

Comment: change `print($row);` to `print_r($row);`

Comment: thank you very much. it working fine now

Comment: you can mark it as answered.

Comment: May be - $row['password']

Comment: You're not using prepared statements. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pw = $_POST[$password];` need to be like `$pw = $_POST['html_form_field_name'];` apparently you are using variable instead of actual static name of the form field.